# On click show 'Div 1' & hide 'Div 2' & On click of separate button show 'Div 2' and hide 'Div 1'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get 2 separate buttons to work so that if you click one button it shows 'Div 1' and hides 'Div 2' and if you click a separate button it shows 'Div 2' and hides 'Div 1'.

I'm not great with jquery or js so only got this far...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j01b1wmn/)

```
$('.button-1').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $('.div-2').hide();
  $('.div-1' + (i+1)).show();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `i` supposed to be?

Comment: `$('.div-1' + (i+1))` ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yjx85ra0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.button-1').click(function() {
    $('.div-2').hide();
    $('.div-1').show();
});

$('.button-2').click(function() {
    $('.div-1').hide();
    $('.div-2').show();
});
```

Comment: no worries mate, best to try and keep things simple, im not sure why you had it so confused  :)

Comment: I know for some reason I just thought it was more complicated than it was!

Answer (score 2):

Hide both boxes, then show the one you want:

```
$('.button-1, .button-2').click(function() {
  $('.boxes > div').hide();
  $('.div-' + $(this).index()).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f45m9oja/)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `+ (i + 1)`. Just hide `div-1` and show `div-2`, or vice versa, depending on which button was clicked.

```js
$('.button-1').click(function() {
      $('.div-2').hide();
      $('.div-1').show();
});
$('.button-2').click(function() {
      $('.div-1').hide();
      $('.div-2').show();
});
```

```css
.boxes {
    height: 100px;    
}

.div-1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.div-2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

button {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="div-1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div-2">Div 2</div>
</div>    

<button class="button-1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button-2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: `var i = $(this).index();`  not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.button-1').click(function() {

    $('.div-2').hide();
    $('.div-1').show();
});

$('.button-2').click(function() {

    $('.div-1').hide();
    $('.div-2').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjx85ra0/